# Using custom HTML as result of Tag-it Autocomplete

Tags: html, autocomplete, tag-it

Autocomplete property of Tagit Jquery plugin was written as follwing :

```
 autocomplete: {

                             source: function( request, response ) {
                             $.ajax({
                                 url: baseURL,
                                 dataType: "json",
                                 data: {
                                    query:request.term
                                 },
                                 success: function( data ) {
                                     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                         return {
                                             label: item.label + "<br />" +item.description,
                                             value: item.label
                                         }
                                     }));
                                 }
                             });
                         }
```

All work fine except returning to line as you see that `<br>` is embedded between `Label` and `description` of item. 
The problem that Tag-it interprets `<br>` such as plain text .

[image]

i read  [here](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown) :

> If you're using a custom jQuery UI build, it must contain the Core,
>   Widget, Position, and Autocomplete components. The Effects Core with
>   "Blind" and "Highlight" Effect components are optional, but used if
>   available.

And i don't knwon how to set custom HTML

**UPDATE :**

Known that if it is autocomplete plugin  , we can use :

```
$('ul').autocomplete({...}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                                 return $("<li></li>")
                                 .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                                 .append("<a>" + item.label +"<br>"+item.description+ "</a>")
                                 .appendTo(ul);
                         };
```

However, when i applay `.data("autocomplete")._renderItem` at tag-it plugin , i get error .

```
$('ul').tagit({autocomplete:{/*....*/}}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem=fn /*...*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me

```
$('ul').find("input").data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) { };
```

Comment: quick question about this method, how I can bind again the old tag it events ?

Comment: - 3 years ago...so , i cannot remember now.. However, I recommend to open new question & explain this sub-issue. @OrcusZ .

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ve done it (I wanted to place an image tag)... add the following (or as per your need) inside `autocomplete` as an option...

```
open: function( event, ui ) {
    //alert(ui);
    $('ul.tagit-autocomplete').find("li").each(function(index){
    var cur_html = $(this).html();

    var new_html = cur_html.replace('&lt;img', '<img');
    var new_html = new_html.replace('/&gt;', '/>');

    $(this).html(new_html);
    //console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).html() );
    });
    return true;
}
```